# To merge k sorted lists, is it bad to merge all the lists and then sort at the end? Is this cheating?

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, merge, big-o

I came across this problem of merging k sorted lists and my solution simply creates an array with all the elements and sorts the array.  I think this solution has O(n log n) time (which seems to be the best you can do with this problem).  But maybe I'm wrong.  Is this somehow not the right solution or not optimal?  The reason I ask is because this is marked as 'hard' problem on Leetcode so I expect there's some complexity I haven't taken into account or that this wasn't the intent of the problem.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode
#     attr_accessor :val, :next
#     def initialize(val)
#         @val = val
#         @next = nil
#     end
# end

# @param {ListNode[]} lists
# @return {ListNode}
def merge_k_lists(lists)
    final_list = []
    lists.each do |list|
        while list
            final_list << list.val
            list = list.next
        end
    end
    final_list.sort!
end
```

EDIT:
Now it makes sense that the best algorithm can be O(n log k) and that can be done with a min-heap.  Does a divide and conquer give the same time complexity?

Here's my divide and conquer solution, which turns out to be a lot slower than my previous solution.  (this one is not an accepted solution since it exceeds the time limit)

```
def merge_k_lists(lists)
    lists.compact!
    return lists.first if lists.length == 1
    if lists.length > 2
        new_lists = []
        mid = lists.length/2
        new_lists << merge_k_lists(lists[0...2])
        new_lists << merge_k_lists(lists[2..-1])
        lists = new_lists
    end
    list_a = lists.first
    list_b = lists.last
    root = nil
    last_node = nil
    while list_a || list_b
        if !list_b.nil? && (list_a.nil? || list_a.val > list_b.val)
            list_b, list_a = list_a, list_b 
        end
        node = ListNode.new(list_a.val)
        list_a = list_a.next
        if last_node
            last_node.next = node
            last_node = node
        else
            root = node
            last_node = node
        end
    end
    return root
end
```

Comment: You can do it in O(n log k), where n is the total number of items, and k is the number of lists. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Way_Merge_Algorithms#Direct_K-Way_Merge, for example.

Comment: A Better solution is to use Min Heap based solution  which has time complexity of  O(n Log k).